# A integration for a probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent uniform(0,1) random variables.

Find $P(XY\leq t)$

My question is when $t\leq 1$, why does it can be seperated to

$P(XY\leq 1)= \int_0^t\int_0^1 dydx+\int_t^1\int_0^{t/y}dydx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the support of $Y$ is $(0;1)$, so

$$\mathsf P(XY\leq t) = \int_0^1 \mathsf P(xY\leq  t\mid X=x) f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\\ = \int_0^1 \mathsf P(Y\leq t/x)f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\\ = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min (1, t/x)} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

Now, when $x\leq t$ the minimum is $1$, and when $x > t$ the minimum is $t/x$

$$\mathsf P(XY\leq t) = \int_0^{\min(1,t)} \int_0^{1} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x + \int_{\max(1,t)}^1\int_0^{t/x} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x $$

Similarly when $t\geq 1$ the second term vanishes and upper bound of the first term is $1$, however when $t<1$ the upper bound of the first term is $t$ as is the lower bound of the second term.

$$\mathsf P(XY\leq t) =\begin{cases} 0 & : t < 0 \\[1ex] \int_0^{t} \int_0^{1} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x + \int_{t}^1\int_0^{t/x} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x & : 0\leq t < 1 \\[1ex] \underbrace{\int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} f_Y(y)f_X(x)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x}_\textsf{which, of course, is $1$} & : t\geq 1\end{cases}$$

That is awl.